# How can I apply the patchValue method on deeply nested form groups in this Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am working on a form in Angular 14. I run into a problem while using *deeply nested* form groups. (It is not a choice to do so, it is a necessity).

In `form.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormService } from '../services/form.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
})
export class FormComponent {
  public accountTypes!: any;
  public selectedAccountType: any;

  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    first_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    last_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    accountEssentials: new FormGroup({
      accountInfo: new FormGroup({
        account_type: new FormControl(''),
      }),
    }),
  });

  constructor(private formService: FormService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAccountTypes();
  }

  public getAccountTypes() {
    this.formService.getAccountTypes().subscribe((response) => {
      this.accountTypes = response;
      this.form.controls['accountEssentials.accountInfo'].patchValue({
        account_type: this.accountTypes[0].value,
      });
    });
  }

  public sendFormData() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}
```

The form's template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label class="mat-label">Fast name:</mat-label>
    <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="first_name" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label class="mat-label">Last name:</mat-label>
    <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="last_name" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label class="mat-label">Email:</mat-label>
    <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="email" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label class="mat-label">Phone:</mat-label>
    <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="phone" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <div formGroupName="accountEssentials">
    <div formGroupName="accountInfo">
      <mat-radio-group
        formControlName="account_type"
        [(ngModel)]="this.selectedAccountType"
      >
        <mat-radio-button
          *ngFor="let accountType of accountTypes"
          [value]="accountType.value"
        >
          <span class="top-label">{{ accountType.label }}</span>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

See **[this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-mnstsm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts)** Stackblitz.

#### The problem

The `patchValue` method does not work on the `account_type` form control that I try to access with `accountEssentials.accountInfo`.

```
this.form.controls['accountEssentials.accountInfo'].patchValue({
    account_type: this.accountTypes[0].value,
});
```

###### What is the most reliable way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Are you still on Angular 8 ?

Comment: Angular 14, but I was unable to update the Stackblitz Angular version. Can you help with that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `FormGroup.get()` which allows you to call `patchValue`

```
this.form.get('accountEssentials.accountInfo')?.patchValue(...)
```

Comment: I did that already, but it throws an `Object is possibly 'null'` error.

Comment: see my edit, use an optional chaining operator for that !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

this.form.patchValue({accountEssentials:{accountEssentials: {account_type:"accountTypeValue"}}});

Answer (score 1):

```
well you can try like this:

this.form.get('accountEssentials').controls['accountInfo.account_type'].patchValue(this.accountTypes[0].value)
 

or else you can also try this:
```

this.form.get('accountEssentials').controls['accountInfo'].controls['account_type'].patchValue(this.accountTypes[0].value)